# In C# code function error timeout but in SQL Server it executes quickly

Tags: c#, sql-server

My function executed from procedure

```
SELECT 
    @temp = SUM(BestB)
FROM
    (SELECT 
         NS.[code_malekin], 
         CONVERT(INT, (M.[darsad_1] + M.[darsad_10] + M.[darsad_5] - M.[khosh_hesab]) / 4) / 10000 * 10000 AS BestA, 
         CONVERT(INT, (NS.[BEST])) AS BestB
     FROM 
         [melk].[dbo].[ATbNosazi_MALEKIN] M
     INNER JOIN 
         ATbNosazi_SANAD NS ON M.code = NS.code_malekin
     WHERE 
         NS.[YEAR] = 2018) T1
WHERE
    (BestB <= BestA + 50000)
    AND (BestB >= BestA - 50000)
    AND ([code_malekin] = @CODE)
```

In my C# webform this code does not execute, but in SQL Server it executes just fine.

My C# code is

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

DataTable dt = new DataTable();

command.CommandText = sql;

if (ArParam != null)
    command.Parameters.AddRange(ArParam);
command.CommandTimeout = 0;

if (Isquery == true)
    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
else
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

SqlDataAdapter dataAdaptor = new SqlDataAdapter();
dataAdaptor.SelectCommand = command;
dataAdaptor.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 0;
dataAdaptor.Fill(dt);

return dt;
```

I have used this code to run procedure and function

Comment: i have use   dataAdaptor.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 0; but not worked

Comment: You might want to show your C# code, from creating the connection through to its disposal.

Comment: Did you try using the *same* database, *same* parameters? That query will run slowly in any database because the expression `(BestB <= BestA + 50000)
    AND (BestB >= BestA - 50000)` prevents the query optimizer from using any indexes on BestB or BestA. The only column that can benefit from an index is `code_malekin`

Comment: I remove `(BestB <= BestA + 50000) AND (BestB >= BestA - 50000)` but query not worked and program no response when exec this query

Answer (score 0):

Your proc use a parameter. This parameter is "sniffed" the fisrt time the proc is executed. The execution plan is built based on the sniffed value. Next time you run your proc, the same plan is used.

Now: when executed from C# code, one plan was built, when executing from SSMS another plan was built because the session settings are different in this case.

So you have 2 different plans, one "good" and one "bad", both built for different input parameters. The easiest way to resolve this is use `option(recomplie)` to your `SELECT` statement, this way the input parameter will be sniffed any time you execute your `sp`.

Or you can get both plans from plan cache and examine them to understand what parameter caused "bad" plan (both plans have in them parameter values for which they were compiled).

You can read more on this here: [Slow in the Application, Fast in SSMS?
Understanding Performance Mysteries](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html)